# Basic JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript. Here's my code:

```
<script>
function text_input_type(type)
{
if(type=='list'){
document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML="<input type=\"text\" name=\"body\">";
}
else{
document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML="<textarea id=\"note_input\" name=\"body\" cols=\"27\" rows=\"5\"></textarea>";
}
}

</script>

 <textarea id="note_input" name="body" cols="27" rows="5"></textarea>
 <input type="radio" name="type" value="text" onclick=text_input_type('list') />
 <input type="radio" name="type" value="list" onclick=text_input_type('text') />
```

I want it so that depending on which radio button you press it changes from a textarea to a input text type. The problem is instead of changing the input from a textbox to a smaller text input it just prints the code inside the box.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Event must not be firing. Missed quotes while assigning function to event in DOM

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot a part. I added it.

Comment: Is the element "note_input" a div or any other element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you in solving your problem.

```
 <script>
    function text_input_type(type)
    {
    if(type=='list'){
    document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML="<input type=\"text\" id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\">";
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("note_input").innerHTML="<textarea id=\"note_input1\" name=\"body\" cols=\"27\" rows=\"5\"></textarea>";
    }
    }

    </script>

     <div id="note_input"><textarea id="note_input1" name="body" cols="27" rows="5"></textarea></div>
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="text" onclick=text_input_type('list') />
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="list" onclick=text_input_type('text') />
```

Try this code, you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, except for a small change.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="text" onclick="text_input_type('list');" />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="list" onclick="text_input_type('text');" />
<div id="note_input">
</body>
</html>
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click handlers with Javascript too—inline Javascript isn't really necessary:

```
var elems = [].slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName("input") );
elems.forEach( function( elem ){
    elem.onclick = function(){
        var type = this.value;
        if( type === 'list' ){
            alert("type is list");
        } else {
            alert("type is not list");
        }
    };
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/D3KCz/).

I'm aware that this can be a little complicated. What we're simply doing is attaching a click function to each of the input tags on the page. We set the `value` of the clicked input tot he `type` variable and check if that variable is equal to the string `list`. If it is, then we fire the code in the `if`. If not, we fire the code in the `else`.

Essentially what this does is make it easier for you. You just put this code in your JS file and you don't have to worry about assigning the `onclick` on the elements themselves (and it looks you were doing it for two of them).

However, your code will work if you surround the `onclick` with quotes, like so:

```
onclick="text_input_type('list');"
```